# HelpGTA 5 social club

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online, rockstar-games-social-club

Can anyone please help me.  I have created a rockstar account and from what i can see on My Daughters iphone she is in the social club, however when she tries to log in on her xbox 360 a measage says shes not authourised to join the social club and to read the privacy agreement? If any of you lovely ppl can help id be very grateful Thanks

Comment: I'm having trouble trying to understand the issue, can you edit your question and be a little more concise on what is happening?

Answer (score 1):

A privacy-policy screen should open when you are switching to GTA Online, just read it like all of us do, and then accept it if you think that it is ok.

Comment: _read_ the privacy policy agreement and then accept it ;)

Comment: @aman207 thanks for pointing my "mistake" out.